# Can i build a Swagger UI for other Swagger-ified API's?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, api-gateway

I have a bunch of microservices built on ASP.NET Core (tech shouldn't matter though), that are Swagger-compliant.

I have an API Gateway in front of it.. which calls into the microservices via REST/HTTP.

Now, if i add Swagger to the API Gateway, it knows the routes.. since i need to call into the microservices, but the API Gateway won't know about stuff specific to the microservice (e.g validation errors), nor should it.

So the Swagger UI on the API Gateway is somewhat 'incomplete', since the pertinent info is in the microservice itself.

How do people handle this? Can i dynamically 'import' the Swagger from each microservice into the main API Gateway swagger output?

Thanks :)